# Problem with accessing variable from function in another file

Tags: python

I need to get a variable declared in a function in another file.
Requirement is that I can't call the variable from `setvar()` function.

`set.py`:

```
def setvar():

    global x
    x = 100

def getvar():

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setvar()
    getvar()
```

`get.py`:

```
import set

y = set.getvar()

print(y)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why is `x` not defined? When I print it in `getvar`, `x` is defined.
How can I change it to get it work?

Comment: Because ```x``` is defined in ```setvar``` but you are directly calling ```getvar```. ```return x``` will find for the value of ```x``` which is not defined

Comment: I thought getvar is returning the global variable when called. What am I missing?

Comment: You should declare the variable ```x``` at the very beginning of your ```set.py``` file.

Comment: I set x=0 in the beginning of set.py, and I get 0 in get.py. But I need setvar function to update the variable. So how can I get value 100 in get.py?

Comment: When you run the other file, you're calling setvar function. If you want the same behavior, you need to call both functions still. Unclear why you expect the global keyword to be hit by only calling getvar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is x not defined?

The reason is because of your line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

As you know, that line means to only run the code within the `if` statement if the program is being run directly, rather than being imported into another program. As you are only importing the `set.py` program into the `get.py` program, the `setvar()` function never got called, hence the `x` variable never got defined.

> Requirement is that I can't call the variable from setvar function.

That's not a problem! All you'll need to do is call the `setvar()` function outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block once, and the problem would be fixed:

`set.py`:

```
def setvar():

    global x
    x = 100

def getvar():

    return x

setvar()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    getvar()
```

`get.py`:

```
import set

y = set.getvar()

print(y)
```

Output:

```
100
```

Comment: I can't call setvar again in the real world code. this is only an abstraction. setvar is already called. But it's my fault that I didn't say it